# I need to use a while loop to stop simulation when it hits one of the barriers and then the other

Tags: r, while-loop, simulation

```
max.simu <- 1000  # max simulation trials
v.simu <- 0*1:max.simu  # initialize trials
barrier.level1 <- 10 # barrier level
barrier.level2 <- -10
v.simu[1] <- rnorm(1)  # first simulation value
sim.index <- 2  # initialize simulation index
while ((sim.index <= max.simu) && 
         (v.simu[sim.index - 1] < barrier.level1 && 
            v.simu[sim.index - 1] > barrier.level2)){


  v.simu[sim.index] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1] + rnorm(1)
  sim.index <- sim.index + 1
}  # end while

if (sim.index <= max.simu) {  # fill zero prices
  v.simu[sim.index:max.simu] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1]
}

# create daily time series starting 2011
ts_var <- ts(data=v.simu, frequency=365)
plot(ts_var)
```

When I run my code the simulation stops when the number hits 10 or -10. I need to code it so that it hits one barrier number then if it hits the other barrier number the simulation will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but perhaps this can do it :

```
max.simu <- 1000  # max simulation trials
v.simu <- 0*1:max.simu  # initialize trials
barrier.level1 <- 10 # barrier level
barrier.level2 <- -10
v.simu[1] <- rnorm(1)  # first simulation value
sim.index <- 2  # initialize simulation index

flag_up <- flag_down <- FALSE

while ((sim.index <= max.simu) && !(flag_up && flag_down)){

  v.simu[sim.index] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1] + rnorm(1)

  if (v.simu[sim.index] > barrier.level1){

    flag_up <- TRUE
    v.simu[sim.index] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1] + pmin(rnorm(1),0)

  }else if (v.simu[sim.index] < barrier.level2){

    flag_down <- TRUE
    v.simu[sim.index] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1] + pmax(rnorm(1),0)

  }

  sim.index <- sim.index + 1
}  # end while

if (sim.index <= max.simu) {  # fill zero prices
  v.simu[sim.index:max.simu] <- v.simu[sim.index - 1]
}

# create daily time series starting 2011
ts_var <- ts(data=v.simu, frequency=365)
plot(ts_var)
```

Not very elegant, and some strange stopping conditions may occur because of the large numbers rnorm() can give. Hope this first step will help !

Comment: Might be "cleaner" to set `flag<-c(0,0)` and check the condition `while ( !prod(flag))` That way you can arbitrarily increment "flagup" and "flagdown" on every occurrence of an out-of-range value without a bunch of "ifs"